# How to delete files or folder on AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, delete-file

I have created a repository using AWS CodeCommit. I wanted to know how to delete a particular file or folder in it.

I have created a called testrepo. It has two folders and a file containing the php code in the source directory with the appspec.yml. I was wondering if I could delete the php code file from the source folder in the repository. I have gone through the tutorial/documentation available on AWS site, but I wasn't able to find how to delete a file once it has been upload to the code commit repository.

Comment: add more information, such as what have you done some far and how you want to achieve the desired results.

Comment: @aliusman done. Can you please tell me now how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

CodeCommit is just git behind the scenes. You can follow the tutorial from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-connect.html) to gain access and clone the repo locally.

Once done, you can proceed as if you are working with Github, BitBucket or whatever else repo.

Comment: So, if I write git rm filename, the file will get deleted?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve exactly, but this command will work, yes.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

using AWS CLI the following instruction should work

```
aws codecommit delete-file \
--repository-name MyDemoRepo \
--branch-name main \
--file-path README.md \
--parent-commit-id c5709475EXAMPLE
```

If the result is correct, you would have output in .json format like this

```
{
 "blobId":"559b44fEXAMPLE",
 "commitId":"353cf655EXAMPLE",
 "filePath":"README.md",
 "treeId":"6bc824cEXAMPLE"
}
```